# Send SMS using AWS SNS - .Net Core

Tags: amazon-web-services, sms, .net-core

I'm trying to use AWS world wide messaging service using C#/.Net Core.

However I do not receive the message in my phone number. Below is the code:

```
public static async Task<PublishResponse> sendSMS()
        {

            string accessKey = "my Key";
            string secretAccessKey = "my secret key";
            var client = new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient(accessKey, 
            secretAccessKey, RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

            string phoneNumber = "my number";

            PublishRequest req = new PublishRequest();
            req.Message = "Hellloooo from core";
            req.PhoneNumber = "+2" + phoneNumber;   
            PublishResponse res = await client.PublishAsync(req);
            return res;
        }
```

---

And I invoke this method in the main function:

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             var respond = sendSMS();     
        }
```

I appreciate if anyone could help me with this. thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

```js
 public static async Task<PublishResponse> SendMessageToMobileAsync(string countryCode, string mobileNumber, string message)
    {
        var accessKey = "xxx";
        var secretKey = "xxx";
        var client = new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient(accessKey, secretKey, RegionEndpoint.USEast1);
        var messageAttributes = new Dictionary<string, MessageAttributeValue>();
        var smsType = new MessageAttributeValue
        {
            DataType = "String",
            StringValue = "Transactional"
        };

        messageAttributes.Add("AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType", smsType);
        
        PublishRequest request = new PublishRequest
        {
            Message = message,
            PhoneNumber = countryCode + mobileNumber,
            MessageAttributes = messageAttributes
        };

        return await client.PublishAsync(request);

    }
```

Comment: You should explain what you've posted here. I understand that what it is is a solution to the OP's problem, but what does this code actually do? How does it work?

Comment: This code can be used to send transactional text messages to any mobile number through AWS SNS. You would just need to change accessKey and secretKey from your AWS account. Hope this helps.

Comment: Is this still valid with the latest rev? I tried this code and inserted the access and secret keys.  I can't get it to work and there are no error messages.  Just never sends.

Answer (score 0):

the following function worked for me.
make sure that the account liked to credential you provided has SNS full access in AWS IAM Console

```
    public static async Task SendSMS(AWSCredentials basicCred, string phoneNum, string message, string smsType= "Promotional")
    { 
            AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient snsClient = new AmazonSimpleNotificationServiceClient(basicCred, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast2);
            PublishRequest pubRequest = new PublishRequest();

            pubRequest.Message = message;
            // add optional MessageAttributes, for example:
            pubRequest.MessageAttributes.Add("AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID", new MessageAttributeValue
            { StringValue = "SSystems", DataType = "String" });
            pubRequest.MessageAttributes.Add("AWS.SNS.SMS.MaxPrice", new MessageAttributeValue
            { StringValue = "0.50", DataType = "Number" });

            pubRequest.PhoneNumber = phoneNum;
            pubRequest.MessageAttributes.Add("AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType", new MessageAttributeValue
            { StringValue = smsType, DataType = "String" });

            PublishResponse pubResponse = await snsClient.PublishAsync(pubRequest);
            Console.WriteLine(pubResponse.MessageId);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: also make sure that the region you use for sending SMS messages is supported by AWS.

Answer (score 0):

For new Comers

If you are using Aws toolkit for visual studio as I suppose

Nuget Packages:

AWSSDK.CORE

AWSSDK.Extensions.NETCore.Setup

AWSSDK.SimpleNotificationService

In your program.cs (.net core 6)

```
using Amazon.SimpleNotificationService;
```

and add your extensions

```
builder.Services.AddDefaultAWSOptions(builder.Configuration.GetAWSOptions());
builder.Services.AddAWSService<IAmazonSimpleNotificationService>(builder.Configuration.GetAWSOptions());
builder.Services.AddSingleton<ISMSSender, SMSSender>();
```

In appsettings

```
    "AWS": {
    "Profile": "aws toolkit profile name",
    "Region": "aws region"
  }
```

an `ISMSSender` interface for dependency injection:

```
public interface ISMSSender
{
    Task<PublishResponse> SendSMSAsync(string phone, string subject, string Message);           
}
```

Lastly your implementation:

```
public class SMSSender : ISMSSender
{
    IAmazonSimpleNotificationService _SES;
    public SMSSender(IAmazonSimpleNotificationService SES)
    {
        _SES = SES;
    }
    public Task<PublishResponse> SendSMSAsync(string phone, string subject, string Message)
    {

        var messageAttributes = new Dictionary<string, MessageAttributeValue>();
        
        MessageAttributeValue senderID = new MessageAttributeValue();
        senderID.DataType = "String";
        senderID.StringValue = "sendername";
        MessageAttributeValue sMSType = new MessageAttributeValue();
        sMSType.DataType = "String";
        sMSType.StringValue = "Transactional";//or Promotional according to AWS setup you choosed 
        MessageAttributeValue maxPrice = new MessageAttributeValue();
        maxPrice.DataType = "Number";
        maxPrice.StringValue = "0.5";
        messageAttributes.Add("AWS.SNS.SMS.SenderID", senderID);
        messageAttributes.Add("AWS.SNS.SMS.SMSType", sMSType);
        messageAttributes.Add("AWS.SNS.SMS.MaxPrice", maxPrice);
        var sendRequest = new PublishRequest()           
        {
            Subject = subject,
            Message = Message,
            PhoneNumber =phone,
            MessageAttributes = messageAttributes
        };
        try
        {       
            Console.WriteLine("Sending SMS using AWS SES...");
            var response = _SES.PublishAsync(sendRequest);
            Console.WriteLine("The SMS was sent successfully.");
            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The SMS was not sent.");
            Console.WriteLine("Error message: " + ex.Message);
        }
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

For usage use dependency injection into your Controller or class

```
private readonly ISMSSender _smsSender;

public MyController(ISMSSender smsSender)
{
    _smsSender = smsSender;    
}
```

and then Send Sms:

```
try
{
    var result = await _smsSender.SendSMSAsync(
       phoneNumber,
           "Title",
           "Message");
}
catch (Exception)
{
    //handle failure
}
```

In order to send sms from your Ec2 or elastic Beanstalk app go to IAM roles and for role `aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role` add permission `AWSElasticBeanstalkRoleSNS` and for role `aws-elasticbeanstalk-service-role` add permission `AmazonSNSFullAccess`